# How to interact with Node JS from client side

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, rest

I am building a web portal to interact with internal databases and potentially run ssh commands. I chose NodeJS with Express for this purpose.

Light weight server-side interactions such as templating or routing I managed with Node and Express but I am looking for ways to do heavy tasks such as DB work (insert/update/delete) or run node code with the click of a button from client-side.

My research brought a couple of ideas however I want to use the one which is future-proof, secure (but not vulnerable to security configurations) and scaleable. Please share your thoughts and guidance on the matter?

- Socket IO (may not be scaleable)
- REST API
- AJAX (Has issues with AJAX and CORS in the past)
- Other approaches????

Thanks

Comment: Use AJAX. And of course you'd need a client-side API, so that's not really an either-or.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what you are trying to accomplish, you should be looking into the MEAN stack. I would recommend that you use Angular4, Loopback (Built on top of Express), MySQL, and of course Node. It is very easy to make an angular sdk that will allow you to use the same loopback models that your server side will be using. As a result you will be able to do your heavy tasks such as DB work :)

Comment: Thanks Sirrele, your response helped a beginner level fellow :) I am interested in using Angular however it will take additional time to start learning. However I will check my options. Thank you again for providing guidance

Comment: I apologize for just reading this! I hope your project is going well! I am actually teaching this stack a lot more now and I am posting new posts every week. Most of the post can relate to use cases that you described above. I can do my best to get you caught up, and if you are a seasoned programmer in general, then it will not take to long to teach you. My website is [link](https://sirrele.io) and let me know if you need anything else.